# Issue with a mapping variable in Informatica

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

We have an incremental Informatica job where around 30 sessions runs in a workflow. We are using a mapping variable in all of them as we want to pick records from last run of the Informatica. This variable holds the date of last run. While running, in every session this variable is picking the correct last run date while in one session it is picking wrong date (`CREATE_DATE>TO_DATE ('01/01/1753 00:00:00', 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')`).

Can someone please give me some pointer to find out why it is giving wrong date (01/01/1753)?

Comment: Thanks Marek for your reply. I am new to informatica so plz help me to know how would I know why it is assigning it this value. Why it is uninitialized. I know the mapping where it is happening. Plz get me some point to check in that. I have created this variable at Mapping >> Parameter - Variable >> Parameter.

Comment: After you define a variable, you need to assign it a value somewhere in the mapping. Can you post the expression your mapping uses for that (probably it will use the `SETMINVARIABLE` or `SETMAXVARIABLE` function)?

Comment: Hi Marek, I am using this variable at Source Qualifer query. Like here - (CREATE_DATE>TO_DATE ('$$CREATION_DT', 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')).

Comment: This is where you use a _value that has been saved previously_. There must be an expression somewhere that **saves last run date to `$$CREATION_DT`** (it does not happen automatically, you need to write cod to do it). Check the mappings that are working properly and look for it.